# How to prompt the user when Session times out

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

In my application when `sessionState` times out, it doesn't respond to the requests. So basically I want to know what is the best practice to handle this situation

a) I want to prompt the user that session has timed out

b) Then I want to take the user to the `Home` Page.

Currently, I am doing it in every ajax requests `error` function by checking the status code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlOfferDetails,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'offerID': Offercode },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#loading").hide();
        },
    error: function (req, status, xhr) {
        if (req.status == 500) {
        alert('Session expired');
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Is it a good practice, to check for it in every requests? is there any general way to do this for all requests?

Comment: An expired session results in a *500* error?  It sounds like there's a lot more wrong here.  You may be addressing the wrong problem entirely.

Comment: I tested by expiring the session and checked in console, it threw `Internal server error(status code=500)`

Comment: Sounds like you have a server-side error that you need to correct.  Instead of trying to add a bunch of checks to avoid the error, just fix the error so these checks aren't needed in the first place.

Comment: Since 500 status code is a very generic error msg, is there a way I can find out whats actually going wrong in my application?

Comment: I guess you have some debugging to do.  You can run the application in debug mode in Visual Studio and examine any exceptions that are thrown and step through the code to see where the problem is happening.  If the error is happening outside the context of your code then perhaps you can increase some logging verbosity in the web server and get more information there.

Comment: Check this post of mine:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/aspnet-mvc-check-user-is-logged-in-and.html
i am sure it will help you out